# Let $\ k,n\in\mathbb{N};\ k<n.\ $ Is there a nice, closed formula for the sum of products of $\ k\ $ numbers chosen from $\ \{1,\ldots,n\}\ ?$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, permutation-cycles

For example, when $\ n=5\ $ and $\ k=3\ $ we get

$$\ f(5,3) = (1)(2)(3) + (1)(2)(4) + (1)(2)(5) + (1)(3)(4) + (1)(3)(5) + (1)(4)(5) + (2)(3)(4) + (2)(3)(5) + (2)(4)(5) + (3)(4)(5) = 225.$$

But is there an nice, easy formula that spits out $\ 225\ $ if we give it $\ n=5\ $ and $\ k=3\ ?$ A formula that would be helpful for larger $\ n,k\ $ also.

This may or may not have to do with [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which I saw mentioned in a vaguely related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the (unsigned) Stirling numbers of the first kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind .  One definition of those is as the coefficients of the "rising factorial" polynomial $(x+1)(x+2) \cdots (x+n)$.  There's not a nice closed formula but there are nice recurrences.

Answer (score 2):

It would be the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ of polynomial $p(x)=\prod_1^n(x+i)$, and we know the coefficient of polynomial is defined by $m$-th derivative of polynomial.

So there can be a form as...

$$
\frac1{(n-k)!}\frac {d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\prod_{i=1}^n(x+i)\Bigg|_{x=0}
$$

I'm not sure it is closed form, but it is a form, at least.

Comment: I know this; this is where the question came from. But it doesn't answer the question...